# Why does docker-compose up not seem to sync volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is a simplified version of my `docker-compose.yml` (it's the volume in `buggy-service` that does not behave as I expect):

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  local-db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      # other env vars (not important)
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-volumes/${DB_NAME}/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgresql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  buggy-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
      target: buggy-image
      args:
        # bunch of args (not important)
    volumes:
      - /Users/me/temp:/temp

volumes:

  postgresql:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /Users/me/postgresql
      o: bind
```

If I do `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d local-db`, a container for it starts up automatically and I find that `/Users/me/postgresql` on the host machine (Mac OSX) binds correctly to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` with content synced.

However, if I do `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build -d buggy-service`, a container does not start up automatically.

**Question:** How do I get `buggy-service` to behave like `local-db`, i.e., start up automatically with the required volume mounted?

Here's the stripped down version of `Dockerfile.test` referenced by `buggy-service`:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-alpine AS buggy-image

# Bunch of ARG definitions (not important)

VOLUME /temp

# other stuff (not important)

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]

# Other FROMs
```

**Edit 1**

A bit more info about what I’m trying to achieve...

The buggy-container I’m trying to get working runs .Net Core as the base image. Its purpose is to run `dotnet test` and generate coverage reports, which can then be consumed in the host, which may either be a local dev machine or a build server (in this case, BitBucket pipelines).

Comment: In general, you want to avoid bind mounts as they make the docker images dependent on the file structure of the host and can cause some weird permissions issues https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/. Are you just trying to make the db files persist between runs? You could just declare a couple volumes below as you did with postgresql but remove the bind mount and device to let docker manage the storage. Then, during the build, copy whatever files you need from your host into the volume dir in the container and it'll persist between runs.

Comment: I'd also suggest avoiding `VOLUME` in your Dockerfile; it most practical cases (including this one) it has no useful effect, and its side effects can be confusing if you don't understand them.

Comment: @Schmango My requirement is to have files that are generated as part of the build, available to the host when the build finishes. I could (from the host) run a container from the image that was built and copy the files from this container to the host, but it seems superfluous, given that a mounted volume should (as per the docs) work for me; but it doesn’t.

Comment: @DavidMaze If I don’t include the `VOLUME` instruction in the Dockerfile, the content’s not only not synced, the directory isn’t even created in a container. Not sure if that’s good, bad or irrelevant to specifying the volume via `docker-compose`, but what I know is that docs.docker makes a poor effort at explaining it.

Comment: Hmm sounds like a strange need. Could you maybe add more detail of what exactly you're trying to do here? What are you building in your container and what are you going to do with them once they're on your host? Also, since your host is a Mac docker is running a VM so even more reason to avoid defining a host path when using volumes as it can behave unexpectedly.

Comment: @Schmango Please see Edit 1 for more info. Is it really a strange need? One of the biggest strengths of Docker is environment isolation/repetition. Running a set of processes consistently each time (within a container) and consuming their results (on the host), does not seem that strange of a need to me? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Regardless of motivation/need, the question itself still needs resolution: misconfiguration on my part or bug in Docker?

Answer (score 1):

> ... followed by `docker run -dit --name buggy-container buggy-image`

This command creates a new container, not based on anything in the compose yml file. Without a volume specification, it will only get an anonymous volume since you've defined the volume in the Dockerfile (I tend to recommend against defining a volume there). You can see the anonymous volumes with a `docker volume ls` command, they'll be the ones with a long unique id and no reference to what they belong to.

To define a host volume from `docker run`, you need the `-v` flag:

```
docker run -dit -v /Users/me/temp:/temp --name buggy-container buggy-image
```

---

From your now changed question, you have a new issue. Your container specifies a single command to run in the entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

When bash runs, it reads input from stdin. When that input ends, like when you run a container with no input attached, bash will exit. When the process your container runs exits, the container exits. From the details available, I can't tell you what that command should be, but a good starting point is to look at other images on docker hub that perform a similar task that you're trying to run, and look at the Dockerfile they use (many hub images point back to a GitHub repo with the full source).

Comment: Hmm, I see. How is it that `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d local-db` mounts the volume correctly? In fact, I don't even need to issue a `docker run`, the container for it starts automatically.

Comment: @Ash in this context, docker is very different from docker-compose. The docker command is a thin cli on the dockerd api to run exactly what you requested, while docker-compose works with the yml file to deploy an entire project according to the yml specification.

Comment: So how do I get the yml for `buggy-service` working like `local-db`? Like I said, I don’t have to issue a separate `docker run` for it; it just starts up as I need, with the volumes mounted.

Comment: @Ash to run your containers using the yml file, you would use the docket-compose command. If that's still giving you errors different from the question posted above, then a new question with the different problem would be best. It's difficult to debug a changing problem from the comment threads.

Comment: It seems like `docker run` isn’t the issue here, it’s `docker-compose`. I’ve edited my question to make it more specific.